# Bootstrap tab callback event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to add my custom function every time after change tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class>
        <div>
            <a href="#logo"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class = "active"></li>
    <li class></li>
</ul>

<div id="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code, from [reference](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tabs.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTab a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is missing in official doc. cool

Answer (score 24):

You should use the show.bs.tab and shown.bs.tab listeners:

```
$('.nav-tabs').find('a').on('show.bs.tab', function () {
    // Some code you want to run when tab is clicked (before the tab is shown)
});

$('.nav-tabs').find('a').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    // Some code you want to run after the tab is shown (callback)
});
```

Other options and listeners available here:
[W3Schools bootsrap tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

Comment: @isherwood so i want to run shown  function only after i have done ajax call in show function block how can i acheive this

Comment: @PawanDeore, I didn't write this answer.  Also, it's inappropriate to ask questions in comments. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Listen with the jQuery to the tabs click:
  $('#myTabs a').click(function (link) {
    console.log(link.currentTarget.innerText);
  })
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS for Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JS for JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JS for Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings content</div>
</div>
```

Please read [official bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) documentation, before posting question like that.